# Wrong hyperlink due to the openright empty page

Tags: hyperref, links

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
.
.
.
\clearpage
\lhead[\textbf{\thepage}]{\emph{Table des figures}}
\rhead[\emph{Table des figures}]{\textbf{\thepage}}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table des figures}
\listoffigures
```

The problem is: when there is an empty page after the lof (lof is an example, it may be the toc or the lot), due to 'openright', if I click on 'Table des figures' (from the list of links) it goes to the empty page just after the lof and not the page when the lof starts.

Comment: Fully compilable minimal example please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\phantomsection` should go to the correct page. If `\clearpage` only goes to the page before because of `openright`, then `\cleardoublepage` is the better choice:

```
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
```

(`\cleardoublepage` can also be used, if `twoside` is not set, because then it behaves as `\clearpage`.)